# I want to replace column name with variable in the syntax results[3].column_name , so that i can print according to the user

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to print a specific column of a mysql table told by the user in runtime (without using if else ,which will make code tidious)

```
var columns = ['D'];

("SELECT ?? FROM money",[columns], function (err, results, fields)
```

IN THIS I HAVE TO SPECIFY COLUMN NAME(D) --

```
results[2].D
```

OR

```
var x = String("D") + i.toString();

results[2].x
```

THIS DIDT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a column by name, but you have the name in a variable, remember JavaScript objects allow access that way:

```
let column = 'D';
results[2][column] // => D column value
```

Your `var x` defines an `x` variable. This, however:

```
results[2].x
```

This looks up a property named *literally `x`* on that result.

It's also not clear what the intent behind `String("D")` is, as `"D"` is *already* a string. Making a superstring?

JavaScript has an interpolation system specifically for this:

```
var x = `D${i}`;
```